# Full Calendar.js Event indicator or count instead of event texts

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fullcalendar

is there a function/method in full calendar that makes event text (inside the cell) instead of text, will use indicator or bullet? for example:

[image]

Or is it achievable? Thanks to someone who knows how to or tried this before.

Comment: You'd have to completely re-write the event-rendering code for the "month" view.

Comment: This is the closest you can probably get without making a custom view: http://jsfiddle.net/sbxpv25p/175/

Comment: how do you turn events in to just bullets

Comment: See my first comment

Comment: Just out of interest, which calendar plugin is shown in the screenshot?